# Selecting data-id value inside html markup that is returned by JSON

Tags: javascript, php, json, oracle

I need to get the data-id="value" which is client name. the data is returned from the JSON data. I tried many solutions but just doesnt work. Please help me,

this is my JSON Pull

```
$('#vendorListDrop').each(function (index, value)
        {
            var initSelectpicker = $(this).selectpicker();
            $.getJSON('invoice/process/process_vendor.php', function (data)
            {
                initSelectpicker.html('');
                $.each(data, function (key, val)
                {
                    initSelectpicker.append('<option value=' + val["CLIENT_ID"] + ' data-id="' + val["CLIENT_NAME"] + '">' + val["CLIENT_NAME"] + '</option>');
                });
                initSelectpicker.selectpicker('refresh');
            });
        });

$("#vendorListDrop").on('change', function () {
       var vendorSelected = $("#vendorListDrop").data().id;
       alert(vendorSelected);
    });
```

its always showing undefined in the alert box.

Comment: `$("#vendorListDrop").data('id')`

Comment: roullie it doesnt work

Comment: does it gives any error?

Comment: You can also use it like this: $("#vendorListDrop").attr('data-id');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your select doesn't have any `data attribute` and you placed it on your `option`

```
$("#vendorListDrop").on('change', function () {
   var vendorSelected = $('option:selected',$(this)).data('id');
   alert(vendorSelected);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`vendorListDrop` is a `select` object. You add `data-id` to `option` object.

```
$("#vendorListDrop").on('change', function () {
   var vendorSelected = $(this).find(':selected').data('id');
   alert(vendorSelected);
});
```